# Change link and text depending on URL after click

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, button, onclick

I have to change an anchor-tag, depending on the current URL. Since the website changes the URL but doesn't load a new page, it also has to change on every click on said link.

So far I've got this:

```
window.onload = function() {
        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var linkContact = "/contact/";
        var contact = document.getElementById('contact');

        if (url == linkContact) {
            contact.innerHTML = '<ul><li><a href="/"><span>Close</span></a></li></ul>';
        } else {
            contact.innerHTML = '<ul><li><a href="/contact/"><span>Contact</span></a></li></ul>';
        }

        contact.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var urlNew = window.location.pathname;
            if (urlNew == linkContact) {
                contact.innerHTML = '<ul><li><a href="/portfolio/"><span>Contact</span></a></li></ul>';
            } else {
                contact.innerHTML = '<ul><li><a href="/"><span>Close</span></a></li></ul>';
            }
        }                                                       
    );
    }
```

But this only works as long as 3 clicks. After that, the button doesn't change anymore. 
Since I don't really know JS, my best guess is that the URL-variable is not updated with every click so after being executed once it just doesn't see the change anymore. If so, what can I do to get the URL checked on every click?